Помогите определить какую структуру данных реализовать? С++
У меня есть задача, в которой ежедневно обновляется рекомендуемая цена бумаги (бумага - слово длиной 1-4 символа, заглавные буквы латинского языка, каждый тикер(бумага) уникальный) - пусть это происходит до открытия торговли на бирже. Далее в течение дня, когда идет торговля акциями, происходит частое изменение их цен - программе просто подается тикер и цена. От меня требуется выбрать и реализовать такую структуру данных, чтобы самым быстрым способом находить для поданной бумаги рекомендуемою цену и сравнивать её с переданным значением. Я так понимаю здесь нужна hash-table, так как там поиск O(1) чаще всего, но и хотелось бы избежать ситуаций с О(n). Но не хочется изначально задавать размер таблицы равным всевозможным перестановкам букв в словах длиной 1-4(Тем более если я не знаю сколько акций подадут в начале дня, чтобы добавить). Прочитал про идеальное хэширование, но говорят что с динамической сменой размера плохо работает.Как альтернативную структуру данных вижу только бинарные деревья поиска, но там поиск О(logn). Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение, как гарантировать очень быстрый поиск и какой структурой. Если что (Использование готовых библиотек запрещено и всякие словари и т.д и т.п.).

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

¿Вам нужная быстрая работа или асимптотическое поведение (О(...))?

Почему вы не хотите массив всех перестановок? 26^4=456976. Такой массив для float это всего 1.74МБ.

@sibedir Просто немного будет странно, если в начале дня подадут 2 акции и они будут храниться в таком огромном массиве/таблице. Просто единственное условие в самом задании по поводу рекомендуемых цен звучит так: "каждый день обновляется информация о рекомендуемой цене акций на день".  Немного непонятно - это сразу 456 тысяч акций или могут подавать свое произвольное количество, но если учитывать что произвольное - то наверное стоит рассмотреть как оптимизировать и память. Вот в этом и вопрос.

@user7860670 Нужен быстрый поиск, с исключением редких ситуаций, "когда для поиска приходится перебирать почти все акции, которых немало".

В том то и дело, что их мало. У вас же не на чипе от домофона это запускаться будет. Строка в 4 латинских заглавных символа всего. И кстати, для таких коротких строк при использовании хэш-таблиц скорее всего вероятность коллизии будет стремится к 0

Тогда стоит начасть с составления набора конкретных входных данных и сценариев для тестирования производительности. Затем проанализировать эти входные данные и сценарии на предмет наличия закономерностей,  за счет которых можно было бы выйграть в производительности. И только потом думать, какой код писать.

@sibedir А могли бы вы посоветовать хэш-функции с минимальным риском коллизий для моего случая? Из хороших знаю полиномиальную как в алгоритме Рабина-Карпа для подстрок и хэш-функцию кукушки. Заранее спасибо

К сожалению не подскажу. Не так силён в теме. Но полагаю, что если вероятности символов равнозначны (т. е. они рандомны) то универсального хэша не найти. Можно следовать совету @user7860670 и искать закономерности

Гарантировать быстрый поиск без коллизий? trie пробовали? У вас тикер из латинских букв заглавных состоит, и максимальная длина тикера 4, что делает поиск по trie константой. В этом случае и генерировать все комбинации не надо, но если придётся - памяти чуть больше чем хеш таблица уйдет.

@tym32167 как вы вовремя. Только что протестировал подобное решение. Сейчас добавлю к своему ответу. Кажется вы правы. Я почему-то на это решение в последнюю очередь думал. Подумал, что 4 уровня косвенности - это слишком. Но нет. Не вылазит за пределы как минимум L2. Работает даже быстрее чем через прямой доступ к элементам вектора перестановок. Ну и по памяти не сильно больше HashMap.

Структура данных -- массив указателей.
В латинском алфавите 26 заглавных букв. Если использовать по 5 бит на букву, то это 1048576 значений.
Т.о. вы можете получить 20-битный идентификатор бумаги из ее символьного имени и использовать его в качестве индекса для массива. Если это будет массив указателей, то он займет всего 8 Мбайт и вы гарантировано получите прямой доступ к этой бумаге

К 26 заглавным буквам надо добавить символ заполнитель для хвоста в коротких именах. На числа битов это не влияет.

8 МB указателей можно сжать до 4 MB индексов в другом массиве указателей.

Прямой ответ:
Суммируя сказанное в комментариях:
Самым быстрым по времени вариантом будет хранение вектора всех перестановок. Это обеспечит гарантированно О(1), но требует O(k^m) памяти.
Причем О(1) для вектора перестановок, это не тоже самое, что О(1) для "идеальной" хэш-таблицы. Поскольку использование хэш-таблицы неизбежно связано с бOльшими промежуточными вычислениями и с бOльшим числом обращения к памяти.
Тем не менее, если асимптотика О(1) в принципе нас устраивает, то можно попробовать поискать подходящую хэш-функцию. К сожалению, если исходить их предпосылки случайного распределения символов, то, буквально по определению, без знаний о законах распределения символов (если таковые имеются), выбрать "идеальную" хэш-функцию не удастся.

Идея:
Есть ещё идея использовать сочетание последовательного хранения и алгоритмов архивирования. Суть идеи заключается в том, чтобы получив набор строк, найти такую трансформацию полного вектора перестановок, чтобы заданные строки оказались в его начале.
Вот простой пример (не дающий окончательного решения, но демонстрирующий идею):
(для удобства вместо символов, я сразу буду использовать числа) Пусть мы получаем 4 строки-ключа, значения для которых нам нужно проверять в дальнейшем. Пусть мы получили вот такие строки:

Мы хотим найти функцию вида N(a1, a2, a3, a4) такую, что при подстановке значений из строки, каждой из строк соответствовало бы минимальное уникальное натуральное число: 0, 1, 2 или 3.
Пусть N - это линейная функция. Тогда для нахождения её коэффициентов можно решить СЛАУ

Имеем

Теперь можно хранить не все перестановки и даже не хэш-таблицу значений, а только последовательный вектор 4-х пар ключ-значение.
Если результат round(N(S)) < 0 или > 3 или ключ в векторе с номером round(N(S)) не равен S (v[round(N(S))].key != S), то входная строка не имеем заданного значения. Иначе, v[round(N(S))].value - это искомое значение.
Еще раз - Это не решение, а только идея для возможного решения.

Добавлено
Идея 2:
задача показалась интересной с точки зрения спортивного интереса. к тому же ранее попадалась похожая задача, и были кое-какие мысли, но тогда до реализации не дошло
Суть идеи заключается в том, чтобы сжать количество хранимой информации  не сильно теряя в производительности. Это достигается тем, что при вводе строк:

производится подсчет, сколько разных символов встречаются на каждой из позиций;
каждому символу присваивается его номер на каждой из позиции

Как показали тесты относительно алгоритма на полном перечислении перестановок памяти может экономится в разы, а производительность в среднем ниже буквально на несколько процентов.
Это происходит из-за того, что таблица для подсчета номера строки мала, и всегда находится в самом верхнем кэше данных процессора.
К тому же это решение еще можно "допилить".
(боюсь, что подробное описание этого алгоритма займёт слишком много времени)

Добавлено 2
Идея 3:
Как верно заметил в комментариях @tym32167 здесь можно использовать префиксное дерево. Я почему-то на это решение в последнюю очередь думал. Подумал, что 4 уровня косвенности - это слишком. Но нет. Не вылазит за пределы как минимум L2. Работает даже быстрее чем через прямой доступ к элементам вектора перестановок. Ну и по памяти не сильно больше HashMap.

Изменено
Вот мой последний на данный момент вариант с решениями:

Solution1: Самое простое с точки зрения кода решение на хэш-таблице
Solution2: Решение основанное на хранении вектора всех перестановок
Solution3: Решение (самое запутанное) основанное на подсчете номера символа для каждой из позиций
Solution4: Решение похожее на префиксное дерево

https://godbolt.org/z/8P3vhsbhj
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using byte = unsigned char;

constexpr char MIN_CHAR = 'A';
constexpr char MAX_CHAR = 'Z';
constexpr char CHAR_COUNT = MAX_CHAR - MIN_CHAR + 1;

inline char RandChar() {
    return std::rand() % (CHAR_COUNT) + MIN_CHAR;
}

inline float RandPrice() {
    return static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
}

// Solution1 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// На хэш-таблице
struct Solution1_HashMap {

    std::unordered_map<std::string, float> data{};

    void UpdatePrice(std::string const key, float price) {
        data[key] = price;
    }

    float CheckPrice(std::string const key) {
        auto it = data.find(key);
        if (it != data.end()) return it->second;
        return -1;
    }

    size_t TotalMemory() {
        return
            (data.size() * (sizeof(decltype(data)::value_type) + sizeof(void*)) + // data list
            data.bucket_count() * (sizeof(void*) + sizeof(size_t))) // bucket index
            * 3 / 2 + // estimated allocation overheads
            sizeof(Solution1_HashMap);
    }
};

// Solution2 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// На векторе всех перестановок
struct Solution2_AllPerm {

    std::vector<float> data = std::vector<float>(CHAR_COUNT * CHAR_COUNT * CHAR_COUNT * CHAR_COUNT, -1);

    void UpdatePrice(std::string const key, float price) {
        size_t pos = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            pos = pos * CHAR_COUNT + (key[i] - MIN_CHAR);

        data[pos] = price;
    }

    float CheckPrice(std::string const key) {
        size_t pos =             (key[0] - MIN_CHAR);
        pos = pos * CHAR_COUNT + (key[1] - MIN_CHAR);
        pos = pos * CHAR_COUNT + (key[2] - MIN_CHAR);
        pos = pos * CHAR_COUNT + (key[3] - MIN_CHAR);

        return data[pos];
    }

    size_t TotalMemory() {
        return data.size() * sizeof(float) + sizeof(Solution2_AllPerm);
    }
};

// Solution3 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// На сжатом веткоре
struct Solution3_PreSort {

    using Numerator = byte[4];

    std::vector<float> data{};

    Numerator numerators[CHAR_COUNT];

    byte counters[4];

    Solution3_PreSort() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_COUNT; ++i) {
            numerators[i][0] = CHAR_COUNT - 1;
            numerators[i][1] = CHAR_COUNT - 1;
            numerators[i][2] = CHAR_COUNT - 1;
            numerators[i][3] = CHAR_COUNT - 1;
        }
        counters[0] = 0;
        counters[1] = 0;
        counters[2] = 0;
        counters[3] = 0;
    }

    void UpdatePrice(std::string const key, float price) {
        size_t pos = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            byte& numerator = numerators[key[i] - MIN_CHAR][i];
            byte& counter   = counters[i];
            if (numerator > counter) {
                numerator = counter;
                ++counter;
            }
            pos = pos * CHAR_COUNT + numerator;
        }

        if (pos + 1 > data.size()) {
            size_t old_count = data.size();
            data.resize(pos + 1);
            for (size_t i = old_count; i < pos; ++i) data[i] = -1;
        }
        data[pos] = price;
    }

    float CheckPrice(std::string const key) {
        size_t pos =             numerators[key[0] - MIN_CHAR][0];
        pos = pos * CHAR_COUNT + numerators[key[1] - MIN_CHAR][1];
        pos = pos * CHAR_COUNT + numerators[key[2] - MIN_CHAR][2];
        pos = pos * CHAR_COUNT + numerators[key[3] - MIN_CHAR][3];

        if (pos < data.size()) return data[pos];
        return -1;
    }

    size_t TotalMemory() {
        return data.size() * sizeof(float) + sizeof(Solution3_PreSort);
    }
};

// Solution4 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// На байт-дереве

    using Layer = void* [CHAR_COUNT];
    using LowerLayer = float [CHAR_COUNT];

    template <size_t N = 0> requires (N < 4)
    void** NewLayer() {
        auto res = new Layer;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_COUNT; i++) res[i] = nullptr;
        return res;
    }

    template <>
    void** NewLayer<3>() {
        auto res = new LowerLayer;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_COUNT; i++) res[i] = -1;
        return static_cast<void**>(static_cast<void*>(res));
    }

    template <size_t N = 0> requires (N < 4)
    size_t LayerSize(void** layer) {
        if (layer == nullptr) return 0;
        size_t res = CHAR_COUNT * sizeof(void*);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_COUNT; i++) {
            res += LayerSize<N + 1>(static_cast<void**>(layer[i]));
        }
        return res;
    }

    template <>
    size_t LayerSize<3>(void** layer) {
        if (layer == nullptr) return 0;
        return CHAR_COUNT * sizeof(float);
    }

    template <size_t N = 0> requires (N < 4)
    void DeleteLayer(void** layer) {
        if (layer == nullptr) return;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < CHAR_COUNT; i++) {
            DeleteLayer<N + 1>(static_cast<void**>(layer[i]));
        }
        delete[] layer;
    }

    template <>
    void DeleteLayer<3>(void** layer) {
        if (layer == nullptr) return;
        delete[] static_cast<float*>(static_cast<void*>(layer));
    }

struct Solution4_CharTree {
    void** layer0;

    Solution4_CharTree() : layer0(NewLayer()) {}

    ~Solution4_CharTree() {
        DeleteLayer(layer0);
    }

    void UpdatePrice(std::string const key, float price) {
        if (layer0[key[0] - MIN_CHAR] == nullptr)
            layer0[key[0] - MIN_CHAR] = NewLayer<1>();
        void** layer1 = static_cast<void**>(layer0[key[0] - MIN_CHAR]);

        if (layer1[key[1] - MIN_CHAR] == nullptr)
            layer1[key[1] - MIN_CHAR] = NewLayer<2>();
        void** layer2 = static_cast<void**>(layer1[key[1] - MIN_CHAR]);

        if (layer2[key[2] - MIN_CHAR] == nullptr)
            layer2[key[2] - MIN_CHAR] = NewLayer<3>();
        float* layer3 = static_cast<float*>(layer2[key[2] - MIN_CHAR]);

        layer3[key[3] - MIN_CHAR] = price;
    }

    float CheckPrice(std::string const key) {
        void** layer1 = static_cast<void**>(layer0[key[0] - MIN_CHAR]);
        if (layer1 == nullptr) return -1;

        void** layer2 = static_cast<void**>(layer1[key[1] - MIN_CHAR]);
        if (layer2 == nullptr) return -1;

        float* layer3 = static_cast<float*>(layer2[key[2] - MIN_CHAR]);
        if (layer3 == nullptr) return -1;

        return layer3[key[3] - MIN_CHAR];
    }

    size_t TotalMemory() {
        return LayerSize(layer0) + sizeof(Solution4_CharTree);
    }
};

// GLOBAL DATA --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

constexpr size_t KnownPricesCount = 10; // количество строк для которых известна цена
constexpr size_t TestPricesCount = 1000000; // количество строк для теста

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, float>> KnownPrices(KnownPricesCount);
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, float>> TestPrices(TestPricesCount);


// TEST FUNC ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define TEST(solution)                                                      \
do {                                                                        \
    solution sol;                                                           \
    for (auto& pa : KnownPrices) sol.UpdatePrice(pa.first, pa.second);      \
    size_t ChackCounter1 = 0;                                               \
    size_t ChackCounter2 = 0;                                               \
    auto b = clock();                                                       \
    for (auto& test : TestPrices) {                                         \
        float price = sol.CheckPrice(test.first);                           \
        if (price >= 0) {                                                   \
            ++ChackCounter1;                                                \
            if (price > test.second) ++ChackCounter2;                       \
        }                                                                   \
    }                                                                       \
    auto e = clock();                                                       \
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------\n";       \
    std::cout << "   "#solution"\n\n";                                      \
    std::cout << "Runtime = " << e - b << "\n";                             \
    std::cout << "ChackCounter1 = " << ChackCounter1 << "\n";               \
    std::cout << "ChackCounter2 = " << ChackCounter2 << "\n";               \
    std::cout << "Total memory = " << sol.TotalMemory() << "\n";            \
    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;                                         \
} while(0)                                                                  \

// MAIN ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
// Инициализация ИД для тестов
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));

    // Список известных бумаг
    for (auto& pa : KnownPrices) {
        pa.first = std::string{ RandChar(), RandChar(), RandChar(), RandChar() };
        pa.second = RandPrice();
    }

    // Список бумаг для тестов
    for (auto& pa : TestPrices) {
        pa.first = { RandChar(), RandChar(), RandChar(), RandChar() };
        pa.second = RandPrice();
    }

// Тестирование
    // Здесь можно менять решения местами для сравнения
    // при равных условиях относительно "прогрева кэшей"
    TEST(Solution1_HashMap);
    TEST(Solution2_AllPerm);
    TEST(Solution3_PreSort);
    TEST(Solution4_CharTree);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

//Solution4 считаю лидером, хотя опять же, всё зависит от исходных данных. Ну и от железа. Ну и от компилятора. Результаты на godbolt.org и на моей машине несколько отличаются. Ну и от разрядности зависит (32 vs 64)

Мне понравилась идея с СЛАУ, но вы верно подметили, что с префиксным деревом может получится и меньше по памяти и даже быстрее. Фактически оно идеально для этой задачи. По хорошему бы занести весь код сюда для будущего

подправил и добавил код в сообщение
